# Ordered vs un-ordered axes values?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

I would like to understand, why must we sort the x axis or y axis in order when trying to plot a function $y=f(x)$. Why would using an un-ordered $x$-axis be the wrong depiction of relationship between $x$ and $y$?

I'm aware this must be pretty stupid of a question, but I cannot seem to find a reason.
I understand that for categorical values (think histogram of cars owned vs number of people, bucket (0-3) etc will still help me understand how many people own how many cars, regardless of whether the bucket is ordered or not, could be 0-3 then 10-13 then 5-8) the order of say x-axis values doesn't matter, but why do we say that we won't be able to understand trend or characteristics of distribution of values if the axes were not ordered (ascending or descending)?

Also, does a normal distribution also requires correct $x$-axis ordering? I could just find probability for a range through pdf and plot it randomly, would that violate the area under curve of $1$?

Comment: One reason for ordered values: To integrate it is necessary to have an ordered x-axis. The area under rhe curve represents the integral.

Comment: The way I see it: If you plot everything unordered but insist on keeping the order mathematically, e.g. $1<2$ then you are just doing something confusing for no reason. For why would you deprive the physical intuition of order but preserve the mathematical one. If you insist that we get rid of the order mathematically as well, then you will lose concepts like "increasing" and "decreasing" which are  nice concepts to have, in measure theory for example (and in real life as well)

Comment: My only point is to do a comparison, as to why if i plot a graph for ordered or un-ordered, the former depiction is termed "correct" and latter termed "wrong". Why must ordering affect the interpretation of relationship? And also to find, if i were to ever use this un-ordered x, would the area under a normal dist sum to 1? Would it even be a normal dist or just a meaningless cloud. Any insight is helpful.

Comment: I guess I'm also asking, why favour the ordered distribution? Because at the end the pdf or cdf or edf dictates the area under curve, and we know, changing the order of x axis changes the distribution shape, then why must we be biased toward saying the ordered x axis along with its probability density must give the correct depiction everything else is not accurate?

Comment: Area is not defined by the plot we give, it is a purely mathematical concept, same with PDF, CDF and EDF. If we define these as usual, in terms of measure and order properties of the real numbers, then plotting is nothing but displaying the information we get.

Comment: So plotting randomly will not affect the information involved. But it is worthwhile considering that plotting ordered (when order is present) allows for easy interpretations  such as "further to the right is shorter/longer time, less/more experiments, smaller/larger population" which breaks down as soon as you move around the values on the axis.

Comment: So we do it only for the sake of ease in interpretation? Is that the only reason? Apologies, I'm not very bright here. You're saying the information won't change, does that mean the shape of say what we define for normal distribution on an ordered axis, doesn't change if i play around with the x axis order? Moreover, if i take a linear function, a line, say y = x+1 , would the shape change here if i were to randomise x? I plotted it and yes the line was jagged and not resembling the ordered, but i could still find the same slope, or values for x? Is it any different for higher order functions?

Comment: This is my last response. Yes it is only for ease of representation. A picture can, however, if drawn appropriately give good information on the mathematics present. If $y=x+1$ was drawn on a paper with ordered axis your friend could tell you the slope is $1$ since they could recognize the line as $y=x+1$. If you draw it on an unordered axis they will not be able to say, with equal confidence, that it is $y=x+1$. Still mathematically the slope is $1$. The first picture is therefore better because it is easier to infer that the line is $y=x+1$ where then calculus tells you the slope is $1$.